# NullPointerException on Range.insert of ZK API on generated Excel files (JExcel/Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, gwt, apache-poi, zk

Favor for a friend, here's her query:

> Hi! I am currently using jexcelapi to
>   create excel files and then I read
>   them using zk spreadsheet. I tried the
>   code found in the documentation for
>   inserting columns and shifting cells
>   to the right but unfortunately, a null
>   pointer exception shows up whenever I
>   try to insert/shift cells. I also
>   tried uploading the excel files I
>   created using jexcelapi to the zssapp
>   (just to be sure) but a null pointer
>   also shows up. But when I try to read
>   excel files created by MS Excel, it
>   works fine. Has anyone encountered
>   this problem before? Any help would
>   greatly be appreciated. PS: I also
>   tried using POI to create files. I
>   also encounter a null pointer
>   exception.

Here is the error:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.zkoss.poi.hssf.record.XFExtRecord.cloneXFExtFrom(XFExtRecord.java:91)
at org.zkoss.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(HSSFCellStyle.java:835)
at org.zkoss.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(HSSFCellStyle.java:825)
at org.zkoss.zss.model.impl.BookHelper.copyFromStyleExceptBorder(BookHelper.java:3308)
at org.zkoss.zss.model.impl.HSSFSheetImpl.shiftColumnsRange(HSSFSheetImpl.java:601)
at org.zkoss.zss.model.impl.BookHelper.insertHSSFRange(BookHelper.java:1942)
at org.zkoss.zss.model.impl.BookHelper.insertRange(BookHelper.java:1931)
at org.zkoss.zss.model.impl.RangeImpl.insert(RangeImpl.java:649)
at data.InitWindow.onClick$shiftCellRight(InitWindow.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.GenericEventListener.onEvent(GenericEventListener.java:81)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:192)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:305)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:328)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent$ForwardListener.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3022)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:192)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1603)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1387)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1107)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:563)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:457)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:465)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> And here is the code I use to create
>   files. What I do here is create an
>   excel file whenever a form is created:

```
public void createExcel(Integer formID, String loc){
    try {
        File path = new File(loc);
        if (!path.exists()) {
            boolean status = path.mkdirs();
        }
        String filename = loc + formID +".xls";
        WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
        ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename), ws);
        workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

From what I've found out, she's using a gwt frame as a bridge to use zk classes.

The original post of this query can be found here: http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/15683

Thanks very much guys!

Comment: Is there a **root cause** of this exception?

Comment: Any chance you could try with Apache POI 3.8 beta 1, and then post the stacktrace for that? (I don't think you should get one, but I'd need to see the POI specific one to be able to help there)

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the error originated:

```
public void onClick$insertCol() {
    int tRow = currSheet.getFirstRowNum();
    int bRow = currSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    Ranges.range(currSheet, tRow, colIndex, bRow, colIndex).insert(Range.SHIFT_RIGHT, Range.FORMAT_RIGHTBELOW);
}
```

The error also shows up if I shift cells to the right.